# Subquery returned more than 1 value error in sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to write a stored procedure in sql server 2005 which will first check if the phone exists in Database. If a row exists, it will give me MerchantID of that row. Else, it will check for CompanyName, City, State and gets the MerchanTID, else it does not give me anything. But i have this error coming up "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The 'CheckifMerchantexists' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead. " Where am i doing wrong? Thank you for all your help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckifMerchantexists]
(@CompanyName varchar(50)
,@Phone varchar(15)
,@City varchar(30)
,@State varchar(2)
)

AS
BEGIN

declare @MerchantID int
set @MerchantID = (Select MerchantID from Merchant where Phone = @Phone)


IF @MerchantID = null 
Begin   
    set @MerchantID = (Select MerchantID from Merchant where CompanyName = @CompanyName  and City = @City and State = @State)
    return @MerchantID
END
else 
Begin
    return @MerchantID
End
```

Comment: Do you expect to have multiple merchants with the same Phone?  If not, you should probably add a constraint or make Phone your primary key on your Merchant table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use "set" here

```
set @MerchantID = (Select MerchantID from Merchant where Phone = @Phone)
```

try replacing it with

```
Select @MerchantID = MerchantID from Merchant where Phone = @Phone
```

But note that you may not get expected results if more than one Merchant has the same phone number.  You may have to consider changing your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your selects so that they return only one(if any) since you only want to check if any exists:

For example:

```
set @MerchantID = (Select TOP 1 MerchantID from Merchant where Phone = @Phone)
```

[TOP-Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Your `@MerchantID` is of type `int`, if more than one Merchants have `Phone = @Phone` you'll get a table. A table cannot be converted to an int.

This is why you get; "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple rows in the database with the given company name, city and state. This causes the second select to fail, since the assignment only works when a single value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue can be addressed as Tim or Jeff have mentioned above.

Your second error message (null changed to 0) is caused by trying to return a null value from the stored proc when it doesn't find a merchant based on the criteria specified. The `RETURN` value must be an integer.

Using `SET` as you do, makes the variable NULL if the subquery doesn't return any rows. One advantage to using the `SELECT @MerchantID=MerchantID ...` method that Jeff mentions, is that if no rows are returned, it does not affect the variable at all. This would let you assign a default value for `@MerchantID` at the beginning of the procedure (maybe 0 or -1), and then have that returned if nothing is found, like so:

```
DECLARE @MerchantID int
SET @MerchantID = 0  

SELECT @MerchantID=MerchantID from Merchant where Phone = @Phone

IF @MerchantID = 0  
BEGIN
    SELECT @MerchantID=MerchantID from Merchant where CompanyName = @CompanyName  and City = @City and State = @State
END

RETURN @MerchantID
```